# Probability of random value being correct within X amount of tries,

Tags: probability, combinations

Let's say I have 4 numbers:

```
1234
```

These numbers have a **predetermined combination of 2** that is the correct value, which could be any of the **following 16**. (1 in 16 chance)

```
11
12
13
14
21
22
23
24
31
32
33
34
41
42
43
44
```

What is the probability of guessing the **correct** pair **within 10 tries?**

I'm not much of a mathematician and have no clue how to figure out a percentage chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that we make distinct guesses!

I am interpreting within $10$ trials as meaning in $10$ or fewer trials. This is the probability that if we choose $10$ pairs, then ours is one of them. That probability is $\frac{10}{16}$.